# Slaughtering with a machine

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, technology, slaughter-shochet-shecht

May one slaughter kosher animals with a machine? I don't mean to ask [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22267/how-is-shechitah-done-without-machinery) about restraining animals, what I want to know is if one may use a machine to actually make the cut, to actually shecht with a machine.

Comment: Is a human involved in making the machine function?

Comment: @DoubleAA See my answer

Comment: I'm first trying to understand the question.

Comment: @DoubleAA Is it unclear?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "machine". A knife is a machine. A [simple one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_machine), at least.

Comment: @DoubleAA True...I'm talking about a more complicated machine, like a [water-mill wheel](http://goo.gl/q44W9h) or something. Something that is not clearly a direct human action.

Comment: See the Shulchan Aruch Siman 7 ,see also the Mareches Hashulchan which discusses the diff between koach rishon and koach sheni ,see also the gemara in gemara I believe 16a where Rashi talks about a water dam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes** and **no**.

---

Surprisingly, Simlah Chadasha says ([siman 7](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=&pgnum=38)) that you may slaughter with a knife that is attached to a wheel (though only [b'dieved](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/702/5323), because of a wheel that is not כח אדם; and because it's difficult to do correctly).
However, restrictions apply:

- The machine has to be human-powered, specifically by a Jew (think handcrank); or water-powered, where the water-gate is very close to the wheel and is released by a Jew [so that it is כח גברא.
  These methods may only be used when the person is actually still turning the wheel (when a person is turning the wheel), or on the first rotation of the wheel after releasing the water (or cranking the wheel and letting go, when a person turning the wheel).
- The knife (obviously) has to be moving in a way that it can slaughter correctly (back and forth motion -- if your machine is a wheel, picture [train wheels](http://www.dreamstime.com/stock-photo-train-wheels-image12292950)).
- None of this can be attached to the ground, because a knife that is attached to the ground may not be used for shechita. See Simlah Chadasha [6:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=&pgnum=36).

Probably every mass-production kosher company read through these halachos, hoping for a way to make it work -- but the restrictions are too difficult, especially the one about not having the machine attached to the ground. So we still do need shochtim ;).