# Shackle and hoist shechita

Tags: slaughter-shochet-shecht, responsa

I wanted to know, are there any Poskim who say that shechita that is done using the “shackle and hoist” method of restraining an animal is non kosher due to the principle of animal welfare in Halacha? I’ve heard it’s fairly inhumane because it causes distress to the animal before slaughter

Comment: Why would that make it non kosher? Or, what sense of non-kosher are you using?

Comment: @KirkBellard Something doesn't become non-kosher because of tzar bal hachaim. If. Aan animal becomes a trafah because of the shackle and hoist then thats a different story

Comment: I'm guessing you are building off Reb Moshe Feinstein's ruling regarding white veil. Something to note is Reb Moshe ruled that 'shackle and hoist' is fine. I think it was in regards to a slaughterhouse in Canada(?).

Comment: Igrot Moshe YD II:13 https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=16&hilite=

Comment: I assume you are reffering to orthodox psak? https://www.grandin.com/ritual/conservative.jewish.law.html

Comment: @kirkbellard Do you have a refference that it is not allowed? or only that it is allowed as above in comments

Comment: Rabbi Genack's discussion of it is that it's not halachically necessary, and makes too many headaches and is therefore a bad idea. (There was the ASPCA pen which had heavy involvement from Rabbi Soloveichik and the approval of Rav Moshe Feinstein; why mess with it?) Not that it actually renders the animal not-kosher.

Comment: highly relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22267/11501 and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/92550/11501 (by the way, once links are inserted, they also appear in the right part of the window, under Linked, with their full titles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tzaar Balei Chayim is mutar if it's in order to consume the animal.
See Simlah Chadasha.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Simlah_Chadashah.24.12